# Ошибка при проверке версии Ansible

Tags: ansible

> configured module search path = None

Comment: Как вы устанавливали ansible: из исходников, apt, pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, ошибка установки ansible.

- Удалите ansible
- Если не удалено, то удалите вручную  `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`
- Установите заново через менеджер пакетов.

Comment: нигде нет инфы про удаление Ansible. как это сделать?

Comment: @U.S.DepartmentofState: а как устанавливали?